# Arithmetics of '$\wedge$' and '$d$' operators

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, differential-forms, exterior-algebra

I don't find arithemtic rules of the operators $\wedge$ and $d$. For example, why does this equality hold?
$$ \\ (u^2\cos^2v+u^2\sin^2v)[\cos vdu-u\sin vdv]\wedge [\sin vdu+u\cos vdv] \
\\ +u\cos v[\cos v du-u\sin vdv]\wedge du \ 
\\ +u \sin v[\sin v du+u\cos v dv]\wedge dv\
\\ = u(u^2+1) du\wedge dv\ $$

Comment: $du\wedge du=0=dv\wedge dv$ and $dv\wedge du=-du\wedge dv$.

Comment: And how can I handle $\sin$ and $\cos$? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Basically you have to use the fundamental equation $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, that holds for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry, also remember that $\wedge$ is multilinear.

Comment: The number of thing that go into an answer from what you might know is large, and you have made no mention of what you already know.  One cannot simply write down a few "arithmetic rules" here -- there are many, and they are not simple.  This question should be closed as being far too vague.